# Office addin attach VS Code debugger instead of default edge one

Tags: debugging, office365, office-addins, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to attach vs code debugger to office addin. We have option to attach debugger but that opens default Edge debugging tools i would like to debug in VS Code directly.ž

This was supposed to be used [Extension VS Codde](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msoffice.microsoft-office-add-in-debugger) but it is not developed any more it says:

```
 This extension is deprecated as it is no longer being maintained.
```

I am running my addin with

```
office-addin-debugging start src/manifest.emulator.xml desktop
```

[image]